# Why is ' Device Tool (Responsive view) ' in inspect element is viewing a page different from the actual resolution?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, inspect

I am trying to make a page responsive. My screen resolution is 1536px x864px. For which I am able to see the below the view..

[My desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VenPb.png)

But when I check the same resolution is Inspect element's Device tool, The result is this..
[Inspect Element view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsvBf.png)

containers are misplaced here.
Now which one should I consider as a correct one?
Why did this happen like this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think in  Inspect Element view you need set % = 100% not 73 % or responsive is fail

Comment: No, that is not the case here.